# Will QtQuick2+ always require driver updates on Windows XP?

Tags: qt, opengl, windows-xp, qtquick2

I want to start learning Qt for developing GUI's, and I'm trying to decide between the old Qt (not QtQuick1) and QtQuick2. I was hoping to use QtQuick2, but I'm confused about the opengl issues with Windows XP. My question is, will it be possible in Qt 5.4 to deploy a QtQuick2 GUI to Windows XP, without requiring the user to update any drivers? If not, are there any plans to make that possible in a future version of QtQuick?

edit: I know that Windows XP is really really old, but a lot of my potential customers are still using it.

Comment: WinXP is dead, why don't you switch to Ubuntu or some other Linux OS?!

Comment: You'd be surprised how undead XP is where I live. And it's not me who's running XP, it's my potential customers.

Comment: Dan, I know, my customer has 4,000+ customers using WinXP... But it's not the future. Really people should use Linux and make do with tools available on that platform. XP is old and full of bugs and hackers love it very much.

Comment: Alexis, You're preaching to the choir. If you can convince all of my potential future customers to switch to Linux, I will happily drop my requirement for supporting Windows XP:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On WinXP, prefer the ANGLE build of Qt5, which uses OpenGL ES over Direct3d instead of OpenGL. If you have customers using WinXP, then it's more than likely that they have never updated their drivers, which will cause problems for QtQuick.

Comment: This page [link](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-5-on-Windows-ANGLE-and-OpenGL) says to not use ANGLE on WinXP, because of bugs. Are those bugs fixed now?

Comment: AFAIK, ANGLE has become much more stable in the last couple of years, so it's worth a try. A large number of WinXP systems do not support OpenGL 2.1, in which case ANGLE becomes the only option. However, if you really care about WinXP support, your best option is to avoid any form of hardware acceleration.

Comment: I've been doing some more research, and it seems to me the WinXP ANGLE bugs are getting worked on. So like you're saying, it's probably worth trying. I was mainly concerned that ANGLE would never work on XP, for some reason I wasn't aware of. But if it's just bugs, and they're actively being worked on, they'll probably get fixed. And of course I could fix some myself, once I get familiar with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you can not expect any improvements for Windows XP. DO NOT use XP anymore. Generally Qt5 has only very restricted XP compatibility (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/supported-platforms.html).

If you want to start learning Qt you should use the newest Qt but you should drop Windows XP.

Comment: Supporting XP is too important for me to just drop it. Thanks for the link though, it confirms that Qt is still occasionally tested on XP.